# How do I use pywikibot.Page(site, title).text when the title has an unescaped apostrophe (')?

Tags: python, mediawiki, wikipedia, mediawiki-api, pywikibot

I have a list of strings called cities, where each string is a city name that is also the title of a wikipedia page. For each city, I'm getting the wikipedia page and then looking at the text content of it:

```
cities = [(n["name"]) for n in graph.nodes.match("City")]
for city in cities:
       site = pywikibot.Site(code="en", fam="wikivoyage")
       page = pywikibot.Page(site, city)
       text = page.text
```

One of the cities in my list is a place called **L'Aquila**  and it was not returning anything for text (whereas other entries were). I figured that was because of the `'`  in the name.  So I used `re.sub` to to escape the `'`  and pass in that result instead. This gives me what I expected:

```
cities = [(n["name"]) for n in graph.nodes.match("City")]
city = "L'Aquila"
altered_city = re.sub("'",  "\'", city)
print(altered_city)
site = pywikibot.Site(code="en", fam="wikivoyage")
page = pywikibot.Page(site, altered_city)
print(page)
print(page.text)
```

**Result:**

```
[[wikivoyage:en:L'Aquila]]
{{pagebanner|Pagebanner default.jpg}}
'''L'Aquila''' is the capital of the province of the same name in the region of [[Abruzzo]] in [[Italy]] and is located in the northern part of the..
```

But the issue is I don't want to hard-code the city name, I want to use the strings from my list. And when I pass this in, it does not give me any results for page.text:

```
cities = [(n["name"]) for n in graph.nodes.match("City")]
city_from_list = cities[0]
print(city_from_list)
print(type(city_from_list))
altered_city = re.sub("'",  "\'", city_from_list)
site = pywikibot.Site(code="en", fam="wikivoyage")
page = pywikibot.Page(site, altered_city)
print(page)
print(page.text)
```

**Result:**

```
L'Aquila
<class 'str'>
[[wikivoyage:en:L'Aquila]]
```

I printed out the value and type for the city element I'm getting from the list and it is a String, so I have no idea why it worked above but not here. How are these different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.sub("'",  "\'", city)` does not do anything:

```
>>> city = "L'Aquila"
>>> re.sub("'",  "\'", city)
"L'Aquila"
>>> city == re.sub("'",  "\'", city)
True
```

Python treats `"\'"` as `"'"`. See the table at [Lexical analysis # String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) of the documentation.

I don't know why the second portion of the code is not working for you, but it should. Maybe you just have not executed the last line. Even if `page.text` had returned `None`, the print statement should print `None`. Try `print(type(page.text))`.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks! I definitely executed the last line, and printing the type shows me that it's  <class 'str'> so I guess it's returning an empty string.

Comment: The hard-coded value and the list value aren't the same for some reason. I printed out their values and types, and they both return 'L'Aquila' for the value and both are <class 'str'>. But when I compare them using `==` it returns False.

Comment: @sam_ur_ai so the strings are not equal but look the same? I'd suggest calling the `.encode('unicode-escape')` method on them and comparing their Unicode sequences.

Comment: That solved the mystery, thank you so much! When I compared the unicode sequences I was able to see that the hard-coded string was `b"L'Aquila"` whereas the string I was pulling from the list was `b'L\\u2019Aquila'`. I was able to fix this by calling `city = city.replace(u"\u2019", "'")` on the city.

Answer (score 1):

Pywikikbot works for L'Aquila as expected: e.g.

```
>>> import pywikibot
>>> site = pywikibot.Site('wikivoyage:en')
>>> page = pywikibot.Page(site, "L'Aquila")
>>> print(page.text[:100])
{{pagebanner|Pagebanner default.jpg}}
'''L'Aquila''' is the capital of the province of the same name
```

Seems your `cities[0]` is different from `"L'Aquila"`. Note that `page.text` always gives a `str` and never return `None`. You may check for an existing page with the `exists()` method:

```
>>> page = pywikibot.Page(site, "L'Aquila")
>>> page.exists()
True
>>>
```